# URLs in comments - limiting to example.com just causes more problems

Tags: feature-request, comments

Picture this, OP asks a question on Stack Overflow like

> I'm trying to fetch data from a URL. Here's my code
>
> ```js
> fetch("mydomain.com")
> ```
>
> But it requests `http://localhost:8080/mydomain.com`

The answer is simple, their URL is missing the URL scheme prefix so you vote to close as a typo and leave a helpful comment like

> You should use `fetch("https://mydomain.com")`

only to get hit with the following

[image: Comments cannot contain that content]

<sub>The *More info* link points to [Why are certain example URLs like https://site.com/ and https://mysite.com/ blocked from post content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208963/158281)</sub>

Now the only comment I can leave is

> You should use `fetch("https://example.com")` (replace with your domain because Stack Overflow is weird and won't let me type something that is literally in your question

See the problem? Can we drop this filter, especially if the URL is within backticks which are not clickable?

---

The other side of this coin would be to prevent questions from containing non-example domains. This filter already works when the URL is complete with scheme prefix. Could it be tweaked to check for un-prefixed `my(domain|site).com` as well?

Comment: Did you read the question to which the error pointed: "[Why are certain example URLs like https://site.com/ and https://mysite.com/ blocked from post content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208963/271271)"

Comment: @Makyen yes but StackOverflow is a coding site where developers asks questions about making HTTP requests **all the time**

Comment: This restriction appears to have existed for >9 years. What about the reasons for imposing the restriction is no longer valid and/or what has changed to make it such that the decision should be different?

Comment: Yes, questions about HTTP requests are made all the time. Using example.com, example.net, and/or example.org is the appropriate way to do so. I'm not a fan of making the restrictions even tighter (e.g. to the point where the example question you provided would have been required to use example.com, rather than the domain they chose), but that's an option. Alternately, you could edit the question to use example.com and point the user at the above linked Q&A which explains it.

Comment: @Makyen _"why?"_, because it creates friction in helping people. My [tag:feature-request] does mention that URLs in backticks are not clickable. The other side of the coin would be preventing question posters from adding domains like `mydomain.com` (without the scheme). I'll add that to the request above

Comment: Just to be clear, rather than arguing either for or against this change, I'm attempting to clarify the arguments on both sides and understand the reasons why the issues and decisions which led to the current situation are no longer valid and/or why they should be reconsidered.

Comment: @Makyen because the number of times I've had to say _"I didn't mean to literally put `/* etc */`"_ is too damn high . There's a lot of hand-holding required on SO sometimes and I'd like to reduce barriers

Comment: You don't actually have to put "(replace with your domain because blah blah blah" into your comment. You could just close it as a duplicate of the canonical post about the issue or failing that, just say, "You need to include the scheme (i.e., `https://`) before the domain name."

Comment: _"You should use fetch("https://mydomain.com") "_ <-- well apparently that works? Does that restriction only apply to lower reputation users?

Comment: @Cerbrus it doesn't apply on meta